# Id jumping from 1 , 2 to 1002, 2005, 2006

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc

Id is jumping from 1,2, 1002 ,2005,2008 . The IdentitySpecification in Sql are set to Increment: 1. Seed:1.
It was working fine till yesterday. It has been suggested that this is a bug in older versions but I am using  VS 2019. How should I solve this? Thanks

Comment: This is to do with identity caching. SQL will reserve a sequence of IDs and discard them when the server is restarted. It's not a bug, it's by design.

Comment: See here https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-to-avoid-an-identity-jump-issue-identity_cache-with-the-help-of-trace-command-t272/

Comment: I have used these2 options
1.Disable the IDENTITY CACHE option at the database level
2.Disable the IDENTITY CACHE at the server level with the help of Trace Flag , But it didn't help. I have restarted both sql and my application. The id's have not reverted to 4,5,6, but still have the old id's(2007,2008) and new one added have 2009 as id

Comment: @StillLearning why do you care? This isn't a problem at all. If you add a lot of data, SQL Server will generate ID ranges in advance for each batch, to avoid having to increment a single server-wide value.  `It has been suggested that this is a bug` the suggestion is wrong. This isn't a bug. In fact, old versions used a single incrementing value resulting in blocking

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am still very new to programming. So it is not a error or an issue if id's of my data are 1,2, 1002, 2005,2006 .